# Windows 8, Random black screens and/or reboot

Tags: windows, windows-8, graphics-card

Specs:(short)

- Windows 8
- ATI HD 2x 5770 CF
- AMD 1055T
- ASUS M4A89GTD Pro

Specs (complete) : [geizhals.at](http://geizhals.at/eu/?cat=WL-97892)

nothing overclocked.

The following happens randomly(!) throughout the day:

1. Both screens (Dualscreen) go black and stay that way (turning them on/off doesnt help)
2. Lights of my CD/DVD drives begin flashing
3. The PC apparently doesn't shut down though since the ventilation keeps running, so I have to manually force him to reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems my PSU was dying. It started making strange noises suddenly and when I replaced it, the other aforementioned problem disappeared as well.